# Passing props from component to TabNavigator - React-Navigation

Tags: react-navigation, tabnavigator

I'm currently working on a React Native project for Android. Now I created a TabNavigator using React Navigations `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`, which displays two tabs:

[image]

It would be nice to use this TabNavigator as a reusable component. Therefore, I'm trying to pass props from the component that is calling the navigator. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to pass the props correctly.

This is the component that calls the TabNavigator (named `TwoTabsHorizontal` here):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

import Background from '../../atoms/Background/Background';
import TwoTabsHorizontal from '../../molecules/TwoTabsHorizontal/TwoTabsHorizontal';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <Background background={true} title="Find Dogs" />
        <TwoTabsHorizontal
          headingLeftTab="criteria"
          headingRightTab="names"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    backgroundColor: '#151414',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

export default withNavigation(Main);
```

And this is the TabNavigator `TwoTabsHorizontal`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import TestScreen1 from '../../../screens/TestScreen1';
import TestScreen2 from '../../../screens/TestScreen2';

const TabNavigator = ({headingLeftTab}) =>
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
      One: {
        screen: TestScreen1,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: {headingLeftTab},
        },
      },
      Two: {
        screen: TestScreen2,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Names',
        },
      },
    },
    {
    },
  );

export const TwoTabsHorizontal = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

As you can see, I try to pass the prop `headingLeftTab` from `Main` down to `TwoTabsHorizontal` to use it as label in `navigationOptions`. It gives the following error:

[image]

I already tried the approach that is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558594/react-navigation-how-to-pass-props-to-tabnavigator-stateless-functional-componen).